# Storing complex userdata

Tags: mysql, architecture, users

Assume a tool where one can create an useraccount, then store 'fields' for that account. Each field can contain zero or more 'sub-fields' and each of those can contain zero or more strings.

I wonder how a proffesional developer would design a database structure for such a use case.

My approach would be:

- Create a table for each user
- Add two rows, fields and id
- store a big JSON object in the first row, which contains every subfield and its strings

But somehow i think that this won't be the best way to solve this and i'm having a giant brain fart.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I won't speak for other professional developers, but I try to avoid that kind of use case. Letting end users essentially design their own databases has always caused immense pain and suffering.

Comment: I would agree @MikeSherrill'Catcall', but consider a tool like, for example, a todo-app where you can not only create simple tasks but also different lists and subtasks.

Comment: A to-do application doesn't require a user-defined database. It just requires user-supplied data.

Answer (score 3):

I did a presentation about alternative ways of defining "extensible" relational database schema at the [Percona Live MySQL Conference & Expo in April 2013](http://www.percona.com/live/mysql-conference-2013/).  Here's a link to my slides:

http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/extensible-data-modeling

Comment: Good slide show. My favorite was slide #2 illustrating `ALTER TABLE`

Answer (score 2):

Why not have just one table, with a key for the user?

```
custom_user_attributes
----------------------
  id (PK)
  user_id (FK to user_accounts.id)
  attribute_type_id (FK to attribute_types.id)
  attribute_value

attribute_types
---------------
  id (PK)
  name
```

Each "field" is just an `attribute_type`. Strings can be stored in `custom_user_attributes.attribute_value`.

However, there are still some questions I have:

- The 'fields' you speak of: are they known ahead of time, or do users create their own custom fields?
- Do you *need* to track the relationships between fields and subfields *in the database*, or is that something that only applies on the UI, and you will let your code handle that?

Comment: Your last two questions would be up to the user to decide. The concepts you just described would suffice. +1 !!!

Comment: The fields are created by the user and are further extandable in the future. I'd say that the relationship can be handled at UI side, yes.

Comment: I implemented your concept and it works very well, thank you so far. But i have to admit that i don't understand how to add a 'subfield'